# Update SQL with PHP form (variable in name of input)

Tags: php, sql, updates

I'm newbie so I hope u'll help me. I need to update my SQL with this PHP form. I googled a lot, but problem is i have name in variable:
`($rowclanky["id"])` 
And simply just can't handle it... Tried a lot of things like adding slashes, etc. But I still couldn't make it. Can someone help me how to figure this out? Thanks a lot guys and sorry for my English.

```
<form method='POST'>;
    $sql = "SELECT id,text FROM clanky";
    $result = $con->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0){
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             echo "<input type='text' name=".$row["id"]."  value='".$row["text"]."'><br>";
                                              }                 
                               }
        echo "<input type='submit' name='send' value='Upravit'><br> </form>;
       }
```

Comment: what issue are you getting?

Comment: Where is $rowclanky defined ?

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

You have not declared the $rowclacky variable. Try the following:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<input type='text' name=".$row["id"]."  value='".$row["text"]."'><br>";
}
```

notice that you are setting the results from "fetch-assoc()" to the variable $row. So when you try to access the columns in you need to get them from the $row variable.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

$rowclanky is not defined anywhere

> $rowclanky["id"]

should be

> $row["id"]

And

> $rowclanky["text"]

should be

> $row["text"]